# OASDI -> Social Security

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Request for tag synonym

`OASDI` -> `Social Security`

My understanding is that they are different names for the same thing<sup>[[1]](https://www.google.com/search?q=oasdi)</sup>

> OASDI stands for old age, survivor and disability insurance, which is more commonly referred to as Social Security. To pay for these programs, the federal government imposes a tax on earned income that must be withheld by your employer. The OASDI deduction on your paycheck shows how much was withheld.

Comment: We don't seem to have OASDI as a tag at all yet - do we need it?